# Apache mod_rewrite querystring problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old website - written in asp. The contact form uses a querystring to decide which form the visitor sees.

If a vistor wishes to just contact me, they may do so by clicking the link to:

```
http://example.com/contact.asp
```

If they wish to submit a fault - they do so by clicking the following link

```
http://example.com/contact.asp?problem=true&.......
```

Additional parameters are also passed after `problem` nb: `?problem=true&Customer...` - however, I only need to know if `problem=true`

In the new site I have two pages: contact.html, and help.html

When a visitor goes to `contact.asp` they are redirected to `contact.html` - thanks to the following redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^contact\.asp$ http://example.com/contact-us.html [R=301,L]
```

However, I am having MASSIVE problems trying to get 
`http://example.com/contact.asp?problem=true` to redirect to help.html

I've found tons of examples - but none of them work.. the page always redirects to contact.html

I have even commented out the above rewrite rule to see if my `problem=true` rule was being over-ridden.... This returned a 404. My problem=true rule just doesn't work.

I've been following examples such as: http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/apache-htaccess-query-string-redirects

So to recap, I'd like to redirect contact.asp?problem=true to help.html, and contact.asp to contact.html

Many thanks in advance,

Rob

Comment: You should really consider to **accept**  your answers (Check the 'V' mark). Otherwise people will stop giving answers to your questions.

Comment: Thanks - I didnt realise you had to tick things off. Took me awhile to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you have tried as far as matching the query string, but the following should work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^problem=true
RewriteRule ^contact\.asp$ http://primarysite.net/help.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^contact\.asp$ http://primarysite.net/contact-us.html [R=301,L]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I had a high enough reputation I'd vote you up as high as possible! Thanks! This works works exactly as required :D

Comment: Glad it worked for you! 1 vote is enough, but you can accept the answer as **correct** to the left of the answer :)